# Points of influence gained by Lord power

Tags: oriflamme

In Oriflamme, say you have 4 cards of your family in a row and reveal the second one which is a *Lord*.
Do you gain 3 points of influence (because the Lord has cards of your family as direct neighbors) or 4 points (because you have 4 adjacent cards of your family) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules say:

> LORD: Earn 1 (influence), plus 1 (influence) per adjacent card that is
> in your family.
>
> Each adjacent card in your family earns you 1 (influence) regardless
> of whether it is revealed or covered.

So you would count all adjacent cards.  if you have a total of 4 adjacent cards you would score 5 points.  one for the Lord and 4 for the adjacent family members, revealed, covered or not.

Note these need to be adjacent to the Lord,  just having family members in the row, as you give in your question, would not be enough.  Adjacent means they have to be part of a stack next to the Lord card.

Comment: as usual I forgot the concept of "stack" which makes it possible to earn more than 3 points by round with the Lord. Thanks !